# How do I remove the first item of an array in twig?

Tags: twig

I have a array called 'Posts' in twig.

Is there a way to easily remove the first item of this array?

So it's structure is just like this:

```
array('post 1','post 2','post 3')
```

And I was wondering if the first post can easily be removed with a function in twig to this:

```
array('post 2','post 3')
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're looking for the [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html) filter.

The slice filter extracts a slice of a sequence, a mapping, or a string:

```
{% for i in ['post 1', 'post 2', 'post 3'] | slice(1) %} 
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

output

```
post 2      
post 3
```

The [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html) filter works as the [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) PHP function for arrays and [mb_substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr) for strings with a fallback to [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr).

Comment: Is it possible to slice it without/before looping through the array?

Comment: Yes eg.: ` {% set posts = ['post 1', 'post 2', 'post 3']|slice(1) %}`

Comment: Thank for helping out

Comment: Is it possible to slice associative array with key?