# get col value of an array seperated with comma

Tags: twig

I have 1 array with 2 keys saved in twig variables and im trying to make a table where it gets the value of these 2 keys: 
0 => "Dockers,AD1234,SortA,1,2,3,4,5,6"
1 => "Dockers,AE1234,SortB,7,8,9,9,9,9"
inserted into >

```
{% for key in page.extensions.TwpSortiment.data %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>size 37</th> //these headers value should stay the same
        <th>size 38</th>
        <th>size 39</th>
        <th>size 40</th>
        <th>size 41</th>
        <th>size 42</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>// this must be key value index 3</td>
        <td>//key value index 4</td>
        <td>//key value index 5</td>
        <td>//key value index 6</td>
        <td>//key value index 7</td>
        <td>//key value index 8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

anyone knows a solution or a cleaner way ? i have just started using twig and dont know much.
the table has to come out like this
[image: table image]

Comment: Combine with [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743021/how-do-i-remove-the-first-item-of-an-array-in-twig) to remove the unwanted columns

Comment: Thanks for yout suggestions, it helped a lot.